# How to print the result in descending order in java?

Tags: java, recursion

I managed to get the result if I enter the base and exponent, but the output should be

For example: the output should look like this

> `>>`base:5 exponent: 2
>
> 5^2 = 25
> 5^1 = 5

I need help to put something somewhere to make this happen...

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class recursion {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        int base = 0;
        int expo = 0;
    
        System.out.print("Enter number for base ");
        for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++)
            base = scanner.nextInt();
 
        System.out.print("Enter number for exponent ");
        for (int j = 0; j < 1; j++)
            expo = scanner.nextInt();

        System.out.println(base + "^" +expo +" = " +  pow(base,expo));

    }

    
    public static int pow(int x, int p) {

        System.out.println(x + "^" +p +" = " );
        if (p == 0)
            return 1;
        if (p % 2 == 0) {
            int a = pow(x, (p / 2));
            return  a * a; // This line
        } else {
            int a = pow(x, ((p - 1) / 2));
            return x * a * a; // This line
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Javadoc for `String.format` ?

Comment: I am not clearly getting that what is your expected output?

Comment: it's like in descending order . . . like 
base is 5 exponent is 4


5^4=  
5^3=  
5^2=  
5^1=

Comment: Out of topic, but an important design note: please **separate** the *computation* part (responsible for the maths) from the *presentation* part (responsible for the print). They **should not** be in the same method!!!

Comment: will take note of that . . thank you for pointing out :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, the following code snippets demands a review:

```
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++)
    /*
     * This for loop is unnecessary.
     * It asserts that the following clause is run only once,
     * which is true for any statements anyway.
     */
        // ...
}
```

```
    return a * a;
} /* if (p % 2 == 0) */ else {
    /*
     * Statements are unnecessarily nested within else clause.
     * The corresponding then clause does not complete normally.
     * Moving the following code snippet out of an else block
     * would have the same effect, but simplifies the control
     * statements.
     */
    int a = pow(x, ((p - 1) / 2));
    return x * a * a;
}
```

---

Within your `pow()` method, you have a `System.out.println()` method. You're calling it for debugging, but it's unnecessary as the process returns normally. As you're looking for printing the operations for exponent as "from user-specified exponent -> 1" (*"in descending order"*), use a loop to print your `System.out.println(base + "^" + expo + " = " + TestClass.pow(base, expo));`:

```
    do // New!
        System.out.println(base + "^" + expo + " = " + TestClass.pow(base, expo));
    while (expo-- > 1); // New!

} /* main( args ) */
```

and you can remove the debugging line in `pow()`.

**Example:** (`>>` denotes STDIN)

> Enter number for base `>>` 5
>   Enter number for exponent `>>` 2
>   5^2 = 25
>   5^1 = 5

> Enter number for base `>>` 4
>   Enter number for exponent `>>` 5
>   4^5 = 1024
>   4^4 = 256
>   4^3 = 64
>   4^2 = 16
>   4^1 = 4

[View a live code demo.](http://ideone.com/G9kwrF)

Comment: . thank you very much for telling me how I should do things correctly, and I'd like to apologize as well since I'm pretty much of a noob with things like this... it's pretty hard for my part (somehow) since I'm just searching the Internet how to do things, do trial and error and then understand how it works .. I really appreciate your answer . I'll do my best to improve with programming

Comment: @Haru Good luck! :) And if you need [some free resources...](http://sayhelloworld.webs.com/list-of-free-resources)

Answer (score 0):

```
void power(int base, int exp){

//Use for loop to iterate through each exp down to 0
for(int i=exp; i>=0; i--){
     int result= exponent(base,i);
     System.out.println(base + "^" + i + "=" + result)//Will display result as 5^2=25
}
```

//Recursively computes the result of b^e.

```
int exponent(int b, int e){
 if(e==0){//Base case occurs when e=0.
    return (1);
  }
return (b * exponent(b,e-1));
}
```